# Why those this not work?

Tags: javascript, html

i want it to ask the password then if the person gets it right he can say his name and it will say hi to him but when i try to run it on google chrome it wont work.

```
        <script>
            var pass = prompt("What Is The Password?");
            if (pass == "lolman") {
            alert("You Are In!");
            } else {
            alert("Get Out Of Here!");
            }

            var nm = prompt("What Is Your Name?");  

            if (nm == "john") {
            alert("Hello "nm);
            } else {
            alert("Out Of Here NoName!");
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: define not work, what error do you get. etc.  Looking at the code above there is also a logic error, even after saying `Get Out Of Here!!` it will continue to ask your name..

Comment: alert("Hello "nm); should be alert("Hello " + nm);

Answer (score 1):

The error I get is `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`, you can fix this by doing a string concat on your `nm` variable:

`alert("Hello " + nm);`

`alert("Hello "nm);` is invalid, it won't stick the string and the variable together automatically, you have to tell it to.

Comment: @Jonatan btw. May as well just say `alert("Hello John")` as John is the only one you want to say hello to.

Comment: no i changed it to:     if (nm != "") {
    alert("Hello " + nm);
    } else {
    alert("Out Of Here NoName!");
    }

Comment: If this is the solution you've decided to go with, please consider pressing the check mark to mark this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run it in chrome console and it tell your code is not valid : " Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

AFter changing `alert("Hello "nm);` to `alert("Hello "+ nm);`  - it works

Hopefully this helps :)
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
<script>
        var pass = prompt("What Is The Password?");
        if (pass == "lolman") 
        {
          alert("You Are In!");
        var nm = prompt("What Is Your Name?");  

        if (nm == "john") {
        alert("Hello "+ nm);
        } else {
        alert("Out Of Here NoName!");
        }  

        } else {
        alert("Get Out Of Here!");
        }


    </script>
```